# "Whom" might be ambiguous

Tags: relative-pronouns

The source is [this article](http://www.newyorker.com/arts/critics/cinema/2013/07/29/130729crci_cinema_denby) (The New Yorker).

> He has an affectionate but difficult relationship with his girlfriend, Sophina (Melonie Diaz), *the mother* of his young *daughter*, **whom** he adores.

To *which person* this **whom** refers? What are the basic rules/conventions for using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say *whom* refers to daughter, because it is mentioned already that he has *an affectionate but difficult relationship* with the mother, which obviously is less than adoring; besides, the relationship was mentioned already. So even if grammatically it is unclear, logically makes sense.

Comment: So, we needed to soar up to a higher level of abstraction to understand a basic grammar element...

Comment: @Graduate I bet abstraction trumps grammar many times